# Get specific nested value from XML file in bash with native approach

Tags: linux, bash

I have this xml file:

```
<project>
  <parent>
        <groupId>xxxxxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

  <groupId>xxxxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

and i need to increment both versions (native). So far i have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
increment_version ()
{
  declare -a part=( ${1//\./ } )
  declare    new
  declare -i carry=1

  for (( CNTR=${#part[@]}-1; CNTR>=0; CNTR-=1 )); do
    len=${#part[CNTR]}
    new=$((part[CNTR]+carry))
    [ ${#new} -gt $len ] && carry=1 || carry=0
    [ $CNTR -gt 0 ] && part[CNTR]=${new: -len} || part[CNTR]=${new}
  done
  new="${part[*]}"
  echo -e "${new// /.}"
}
allFiles=("./pom.xml" "./pmaddon-cloud/pom.xml" "./pmaddon-server/pom.xml" "./pmaddon-core/pmaddon-ccpm/pom.xml" "./pmaddon-core/pmaddon-config/pom.xml" "./pmaddon-app-js/pom.xml")

for entry in ${allFiles[@]}; do
  PARENT=$(grep -oPm1 "(?<=<version>)[^<]+" <<< $(cat $entry))
  echo "$entry is version $PARENT"
  MODULE=???
done
```

This kind of works for the parent version value but i need to be able to replace them both separately for every iteration so they can be evaluated separately.

Comment: can you elaborate on your "native approach" constraint?  your script makes use of `grep`, so you seem okay with external commands;  something like this is a **lot** easier in Perl, and `perl` is commonly available wherever `bash` and `grep` are;  what prevents you from doing this in Perl, and calling that `perl` script from your `bash` script?

Comment: i need it to be available in ubuntu server editions without need of installing additional packages. Nothing prevents me from using perl, i just have no knowledge in perl. I also need to increment the value of `version` and have already done that in bash so i guess this is why i went with bash for everything

Comment: I hear you;  the thing is, parsing XML with regex and string ops is notoriously fragile; perl (etc.) have DOM libs (and lots of example code) that make it easier, but -- more importantly -- make it much more robust;  in my experience, a constraint like "without additional packages" is usually rooted in some other constraint, such as needing unattended operation, which not everyone realizes can in fact be fully automated;  I sincerely believe you will be better off attacking the "no additional packages" constraint, so that you can attack this XML parsing with something more suitable than bash

Comment: i am already considering Python as a bash replacement since it is already pre-installed. Also i already have some knowledge there so i guess this will be my approach